# Nvidia - Enable threaded optimisation

Tags: nvidia, settings, nvidia-settings

I often see people write how enabling "Threaded Optimization" in the nVidia control panel (on Windows) can improve performance in certain situations. However I can't seem to find that option in the nVidia Settings on Ubuntu. Are there other ways to enable threaded optimization?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot enable it by default on all applications (yet), because of the following reason ([according to NVIDIA](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/319.32/README/openglenvvariables.html)):

> These optimizations typically benefit CPU-intensive applications, but might cause a decrease of performance in applications that heavily rely on synchronous OpenGL calls [...]. Because of this, they are currently disabled by default.

Instead, you're going to have to run your OpenGL application (games eg.) as follows:

```
env LD_PRELOAD="libpthread.so.0 libGL.so.1" __GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 yourcommand
```

If you don't do that, a lot of games will not perform as well as they could (Source games being the most notable).

Answer (score 0):

From what I know the Xorg driver that is included handles a lot of that stuff under the hood, with a lot of dynamic configuration for optimal performance. it's not really necessary to change those settings manually.

Comment: But is there really no way to change the settings manually?

Comment: I don't think so, anyways the best you can do it you are really getting bad 3d performance is reduce the desktop effects, or if you are using unity switch to a lighter dm such as lxde or xfce